# Number doesn't seem to multiply

Tags: python

```
import random

money=int(0) # money starts at 0 always
bet=int(input("enter a bet.")) # user inputs a bet.
winningnumber=(random.randint(0,30)) # chooses random integer from 0 - 30, stores it as variable winningnumber
number = int(input("Pick a number 0-30"))
if number % 2 == 0: #checks if number is divisible by 2
    print("The number was even, you get 2x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = float(bet) * float(2)  # multiplies the bet by 2
else:
    money = bet+0 # doesnt add anyuthing to the bet

if number % 10 ==0:  #checks if number is divisible by 10
    print("The number was a multiple of 10, you get 3x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = bet*3  # multiplies the bet by 3
else:
    money = bet+0 # doesnt add anyuthing to the bet
primenum = ["3","5","7","11","13","17","19","23","29"] #list of prime numbers

if number == primenum ==0: #if number chosen by user = one of the numbers on the list, the user wins.
    print("The number was a prime number, you get 5x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = bet*5 # multiplies the bet by 5
else:
    money=bet+0  # doesnt add anything to the bet

print("the winning number was",winningnumber) #shows the player the winning number
print("Your money for the end of the round is",money) #prints money at end of round
```

Why doesn't this code work? I have tried multiple different ways yet the bet doesn't seem to multiply.
I was expecting the code number to be multiplied at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You have three different `if-else` blocks. All three do different things to `money` if their respective conditions evaluate to `True`. However, if the last `if-else` block evaluates `False`, then regardless of what happened in the previous `if-else` blocks, the code in the final `else` block will run. That code sets `money` back to the original bet.

You can see this happening if you introduce `print (money)` after each `if-else` block and re-run your code.

Also - it's not clear to me how `number == primenum == 0` would ever evaluate to `True`. `primenum` is a list of strings. `number` is an `int`. Therefore, this condition will never evaluate to `True`.

If what you're trying to do is check whether `number` is prime, then I would (first), define `primenum` as a list of integers, like so:

```
primenum = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29] #list of prime numbers
```

and then, change the criterion in your last `if-else` block to:

```
if number in primenum:
```

One way to make your `if-else` blocks work would be to use `if-elif-else`, like so:

```
import random
money=int(0) # money starts at 0 always
bet=int(input("enter a bet.")) # user inputs a bet.
winningnumber=(random.randint(0,30)) # chooses random integer from 0 - 30, stores it as variable winningnumber

primenum = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29] #list of prime numbers
number = int(input("Pick a number 0-30"))

if number % 10 == 0: 
    print("The number was a multiple of 10, you get 3x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = float(bet) * float(2)  
elif number % 2 == 0:  
    print("The number was even, you get 2x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = bet*3  
if number in primenum: #if number chosen by user = one of the numbers on the list, the user wins.
    print("The number was a prime number, you get 5x your money.") #prints the users winnings
    money = bet*5 # multiplies the bet by 5
else:
    money=bet+0  # doesnt add anything to the bet

print("the winning number was",winningnumber) #shows the player the winning number
print("Your money for the end of the round is",money) #prints money at end of round
```

Bear in mind that "winningnumber" hasn't played a role in the program at all - except to be generated at the start, and printed to screen at the end. The above may not reflect your original intent, it's just ONE way in which the control-flow could be made to work so you reliably modify `money` when any of the three conditions evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code relates to the multiple `if-else` blocks.
You have a problem with your prime number section, which will **always** equate to **False**, and as such you will set `money=bet+0` - which will **override** any other successful changes made to money.

Your winning number does not seem to have any impact on the flow of code, so as long as you choose an even number or a number divisible by 10, it should multiply. But then when you get to the section to test if it is a prime number, it will ALWAYS equate to FALSE, and as mentioned before will set `money=bet+0` - and undo anything done prior.

You need to make sure that you set `money = money + (bet + 0)`
This way your cumulative effects are maintained. You have to do this for the other money calculations as well.

And you need to fix the prime number section:

```py
primenum = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]

if number in primenum:
...
```

Here is the complete code based on what I think you were trying to do:

```py
import random
money=0 # money starts at 0 always
bet=int(input("enter a bet.")) # user inputs a bet.
winningnumber=(random.randint(0,30)) # chooses random integer from 0 - 30, stores it as variable winningnumber
number = int(input("Pick a number 0-30"))
primenum = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29] #list of prime numbers

if winningnumber == number:
    if number % 2 == 0: #checks if number is divisible by 2
        print("The number was even, you get 2x your money.") #prints the users winnings
        money = money + (bet * 2)  # multiplies the bet by 2
    else:
        money = money + (bet + 0) # doesn't add anything to the bet

    if number % 10 == 0:  #checks if number is divisible by 10
        print("The number was a multiple of 10, you get 3x your money.") #prints the users winnings
        money = money + (bet * 3)  # multiplies the bet by 3
    else:
        money = money + (bet + 0) # doesn't add anything to the bet

    if number in primenum: #if number chosen by user = one of the numbers on the list, the user wins.
        print("The number was a prime number, you get 5x your money.") #prints the users winnings
        money = money + (bet * 5) # multiplies the bet by 5
    else:
        money = money + (bet + 0) # doesn't add anything to the bet

print("the winning number was",winningnumber) #shows the player the winning number
print("Your money for the end of the round is",money) #prints money at end of round
```